# Symfony doctrine multiple count

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony

I try to retrieve multiple count in a single query on a single table.

```
return $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery(
        'SELECT COUNT(c1) AS enabled, COUNT(c2) AS disabled, COUNT(c3) AS locked
        FROM AcmeUserBundle:User c1, AcmeUserBundle:User c2, AcmeUserBundle:User c3
        WHERE c1.enabled = 1
        AND c2.enabled = 0
        AND c3.locked = 1'
    )->getSingleResult();
```

With this action I get this result:

```
array [
  "enabled" => "4"
  "disabled" => "4"
  "locked" => "4"
]
```

The result that I expected would be this:

```
array [
  "enabled" => "2"
  "disabled" => "1"
  "locked" => "1"
]
```

I get that a simple count of the entire table.

Some body knows how i can make it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL query is wrong. You are doing cross join of three tables, but you want to count rows that satisfy some condition in the table:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN u.enabled = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as enabled,
       SUM(CASE WHEN u.enabled = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as disabled,
       SUM(CASE WHEN u.locked = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as locked
FROM AcmeUserBundle:User u
```